# Android Webview intercept a chat message into a Toast

Tags: android, webview, chat, toast, vibration

Is it possible to intercept a chat message and highlighting via Toast & vibration with WebView?

On a phone or tablet, your browser is open. WebView has loaded the page where the chat is.

From there - I'd like to know - whether it is possible to catch a chat message via WebView and then to highlighting by Toast & vibration.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: You might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)